# How to understand this C operators question?

Tags: c, for-loop, bit-shift, operator-precedence, addition

I just started to learn C programming with books, and I found a part of the code shown below. When I run this code, the result was another value (2008000) instead of **0xffff**.

```
int i = 0;
unsigned int sum = 0;
for(; i < 16; i++)
    sum = sum + 1U << i
```

Why is this result completely different from the expected output?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `sum = sum + (1U << i);` operator precedence.

Comment: Addition has higher precedence than shift. Replace with `sum + (1U << i)`.

Comment: I would expect `536903680` which is the same value as `0x20008000`, which is very different than `20008000`.

Comment: Note that `sum += 1U << i;` would give you the desired result.  It is shorthand for `sum = sum + (1U << i);` — except that `sum` is only evaluated once (which matters if you have a complex expression like `ptr->data.array[k][2]`) and the expression on the RHS of the `+=` operator is evaluated before adding the result to the variable on the LHS.

Comment: The fact that the code isn't written as `for(int i=0; i < 16; i++)` suggests that your learning material is some 30 years old and completely outdated.

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet

```
for(; i < 16; i++)
    sum = sum + 1U << i
                      ^^^
```

where you forgot to place an ending semicolon the expression `sum + 1U << i` is equivalent to `( sum + 1U ) << i` due to the operator precedence.

It seems that instead you mean `sum + ( 1U << i )`.